# using request query parameters , react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, query-string

I have an issue with link parameters:

E.g. I want something like this,
http://my-project.com/list?city=whatever&limit=20
Now I had done everything and made a html select tag 
When you choose any city you’ll find what you want

But when you refresh the page you will lose you selected 
Then you have to reselect the city again because
the link still looks like: `....com/list` , although I have 
already declare a request query in my call link (using axios) 
in my react component.

So my question is, How can I declare it in my switch routes!?
My demo is here : https://shadi-final-project.herokuapp.com

Comment: It's normal that you lose your state values when you refresh your page. But u can make some url query parameter something like https://shadi-final-project.herokuapp.com/list?selectedCity=paris, and then when refreshing page checking if you have anything in ?selectedCitiy. That way you can reinitialize your selected values

Comment: oke but how ? @ivica.moke

Answer (score 0):

query param can be a bit tricky, but u can use localStorage like this:

**this is just example**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const options = ["one", "two", "more", "set", "blah"]

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue: localStorage.getItem("selectedValue") || null
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: e.target.value });
    localStorage.setItem("selectedValue", e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <select onChange={this.onChange} value={selectedValue ? selectedValue : options[0]}>
        {options.map((option, index) => <option key={index}>{option}</option>)}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

That is some rough example but it's working, try to tweak it until it fits your needs.

Comment: that makes sense but i want another way by using just query string and pros.location.search